# Comparing AM and PM (NSDate)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdate, datetime-comparison

I have two times both in String format:

```
timeOne = "12:58 AM"
timeTwo = "1:05 PM"
```

I convert them into NSDate like this

```
func convertTime(tim: String) -> NSDate{
let strDate = tim
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
//converts into NSDate so we can find the time remaining
return (dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate))!
}

let tOne = convertTime(timeOne)
let tTwo = convertTime(timeTwo)
```

converting tOne and tTwo outputs me

```
tOne = 2000-01-01 00:58:00 +0000
tTwo = 2000-01-01 12:05:00 +0000
```

I compare the two times but i want it to return 7 mins whereas im getting '667'
The code to compare is:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.Minute, fromDate: tOne, toDate: tTwo, options: [])
print(components)
```

This prints out

```
667
```

However it works if the both times are the same AM or PM 
What i mean by this is that lets say

```
tOne = "1:06 PM"
tTwo = "1:15 PM"
```

running the comparison code it successfully outputs "9"

Comment: What's the value of `tOne` and `tTwo` in your example?

Comment: I think you are mistaken in your use of a.m. - 12:58 a.m. is only meaningful as 00:58, not 12:58, which would be p.m. = *post meridian* - i.e. "after noon". Therefore it is 11 hours 7 minutes = 667 minutes between the times.

Comment: I edited it check the value

Comment: Try and use your code in Playground, your output is `tOne = 12:58 AM` and `tTwo = 12:05 PM`

Comment: How would i fix this 11 hours 7 minute?

Comment: what do u want to fix? it is 11 hours and 7 minutes.

Comment: so i have 12:58 AM and 1:05 PM find the correct minutes left from tOne and tTwo

Comment: the correct time difference: 11 hours and 7 minutes.

Comment: How would i change it so it can out put 7 minutes?

Comment: give it dates that have 7 minutes difference, like "12:58 PM" and "1:05 PM"

Comment: but it is 7 minutes in the 'real world' because 7 minutes add 12:58 = 1:05?

Comment: Transform `12:58 AM` to `12:58 PM` It should gives your 7 minutes.

Comment: 12:58 *AM* is just 58 minutes past midnight. 1:05 *PM* is 65 minutes past noon. did you now get it?

Comment: @MinhalKhan: Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock.

Comment: You don't understand what `12:58 AM` means. Understand what "real time" it is, then come back. That's why I invited you to check the values of `tOne`, it was an hint to let you understand. I quite guess that you are use a a 24h format and not a AM/PM one, but if you don't understand it, you can't work with it. The "7" minutes you want, is either because the original infos of `12:58 AM` is wrong, or if it's correct, then the REAL difference between the two hours is 667 minutes.

Comment: Actually the date format for the 12-hour clock is **"hh:mm a"** (with lowercase "hh"), and with that you'll get the correct difference of **727 minutes** (12 hours and 7 minutes).

Comment: OHHHHH sorry cause i have never used time in xcode so i really wouldnt understand it, but i got it Thanks! everyone

Answer (score 1):

your understanding of am and pm times seems to be false.

The times aren't 7 minutes in difference, the first is just after midnight, the second 65 minutes after noon.

[image]

If you fix your code as suggested by MartinR, the correct difference will be 12 hours and 7 minutes.